# jBPM 6.5.0.FInal look up email in active directory

Tags: email, active-directory, jbpm

My jBPM does not read the userinfo from active directory

I used the jbpm 6.5.0.Final installer, modified the standalone-full.xml to add active directory, setup the jbpm-roles.properties, jbpm.user.info.properties, jbpm.usergroup.callback.properties files to point to active directory
I added the following lines to the standalone-full.xml system properties

- <property name="jbpm.usergroup.callback.properties" value="file:../standalone/configuration/jbpm.usergroup.callback.properties"/>
- <property name="jbpm.user.info.properties" value="file:../standalone/configuration/jbpm.user.info.properties"/>
- <property name="org.kie.mail.session" value="java:jboss/mail/Default"/>
- <property name="org.jbpm.ht.callback" value="ldap"/>
- <property name="org.jbpm.ht.userinfo" value="ldap"/

I am able to login using the active directory account, then setup a process that sends a notification.

Most of the email is not sent and I get the error message
ERROR [org.jbpm.services.task.deadlines.notifications.impl.email.EmailNotificationListener] (pool-24-thread-1) Unable to send email notification due to No EMail address found for testUser

using eclipse, i can see that the registry has user and group information taken UserGroupsAssignmentsOne.mvel and no call is made to LDAPUserInfoImpl.getEmailForEntity()

Comment: additional information: if i schedule a notification, restart jboss, the notification is delivered, but if i sechedule a second notification, i get the "no email address for user"

Comment: Hi Sohail, can you share the .properties config files?